# Relative layout and navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

I am new to android i have a relative layout and i am implementing navigation drawer to it, so how to place it i dont know. Swipe in and out is not working... when i created a new project with DrawerLayout and FrameLayout it is working but when i implemented on my project it is malfunctioning

```
activity_main.xml
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/calc" >




    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:background="#00a77f"

        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />





    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearll1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cs"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:text="@string/cs"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:text="@string/maincalc"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearll2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearll1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/interviewquestion"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:text="@string/interview_ques"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/careerGuidance"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:text="@string/career_guid"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearll2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/aboutme"
                android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity:
    MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] navdra;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListner;

    Intent shareintent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navdra = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navdra);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, navdra));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListner = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.dopen, R.string.dclose);



        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListner);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        Button csv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cs);
        csv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Semester.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        Button cal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cal);
        cal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Calculator.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        Button iq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.interviewquestion);

        iq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        InterviewQuestion.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        Button cg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.careerGuidance);
        cg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Careerguid.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        Button abt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
        abt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PKlabs!!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Intent intent = new Intent
                // (v.getContext(),InterviewQuestion.class);
                // startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListner.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListner.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem item = menu.add("share"); // your desired title here
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.share_icon); // your desired icon here
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                shareintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareintent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                shareintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "Subject Here");
                shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "Share via"));
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(drawerListner.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }




        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, navdra[position] + " selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(navdra[position]);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }




    private Toast toast;
    private long lastBackPressTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: For some reason if i use a Relative layout the contents do not show, but if i switch and use a LinearLayout i get to see the contents of my view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 1st element in the `DrawerLayout` is the activity content (in your case a `RelativeLayout`). The 2nd one is the drawer itself (`ListView` for you).

Change your layout to this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/calc" >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearll1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cs"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/cs"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cal"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/maincalc"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearll2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearll1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/interviewquestion"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/interview_ques"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/careerGuidance"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/career_guid"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearll2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/aboutme"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:background="#00a77f"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @PUNEET what is your drawer supposed to be? A `ListView` only or the whole `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: a listview, relative layout is my main page

Comment: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed,  this error is coming

Comment: @Simas Thanks for your answer, i had the similar issue and your with your logic i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first
>   child with a width and height of match_parent. Add drawers as child
>   views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity
>   appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a
>   fixed width.

(Android docs [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html))

Add the following line to your relative layout :

> android:layout_gravity="left|start"

Answer (score 0):

That's because `layout_gravity` don't work with RelativeLayout. Use a frame layout instead.

**EDIT**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:background="#00a77f"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:background="@drawable/calc">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearll1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cs"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/cs"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cal"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/maincalc"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearll2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearll1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/interviewquestion"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/interview_ques"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/careerGuidance"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                        android:text="@string/career_guid"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearll2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:alpha="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/aboutme"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/recbutcolor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @PUNEET Test it now please

Comment: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix, ERROR

Comment: Check if you really copy and pasted correctly. All attributes have the `android` prefix.

Comment: No problem. If you need a template for your work with material design a navigation drawer check out my project here: https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template